# Retrieving Function parameters values in aws lambda using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have 2 aws lambda functions i.e. "LambdaChain1" and "LambdaChain2"
i am calling aws lambda function "LambdaChain2" from aws lambda function "LambdaChain1" as follows :

`enter code here` var start=new Date();
`enter code here`console.log('Loading function');

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    event.Records.forEach(function(record) {
        // Kinesis data is base64 encoded so decode here
        var payload = new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('ascii');
        console.log('Decoded payload:', payload);
    });
    context.succeed("Successfully processed " + event.Records.length + " records.");
    var params = {
  FunctionName: 'LambdaChain2', /* required */
  InvokeArgs: start.getTime() /* required */
};
lambda.invokeAsync(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
};
```

Now we can see from the code that I have passed "start.getTime()" as parameter to aws lambda function "LambdaChain2"....

I want to know that in aws lambda function LambdaChain2 how can I retrieve or use the parameter that I have passed to the function "LambdaChain2" from lambda function "LambdaChain1".....Can you please provide an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `invokeAsync` is deprecated, so I used `invoke` for this example, but it is fairly similar.

The `Payload` argument in the `invoke` params becomes the `event` parameter in ChainFunc2.

**ChainFunc1**

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    var params = {
        FunctionName: "ChainFunc2",
        InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
        Payload: JSON.stringify({"greeting": "Hello, Lambda"})
    };
    var lambdaClient = new AWS.Lambda();
    lambdaClient.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("invoke failed:" + err, err.stack);
            context.fail(err);
        } else {
            console.log("invoke succeeded", data);
            context.succeed(data);
        }
    });
};
```

**ChainFunc2**

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log("Received event:", JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    console.log("Greeting:", event.greeting);
    context.succeed({"message": "ChainFunc2 processed this", "payload": event});
};
```

Comment: Your solution is working when i am using the parameter of ChainFunc1 in ChainFunc2....But now I am not able to use the same in ChainFunc3,4,5...Basically I want to use the same parameter with same value in other functions also....I can see from the logs that JSON.stringify(event,null,2) returns null from ChainFunc3 & returns not null in 1 & 2.....How can I be able to use the parameter greeting in another lambda functions?? Do I have to make separate approach if I am using Long or Integer values in node js

Comment: How did you pass the parameter from ChainFunc2 to ChainFunc3, 4, etc?  You will have to keep passing the same values along.

Comment: I want to pass milliseconds throughout my lambda function. This is my code for ChainFunc1 ::              var AWS = require("aws-sdk");           var starttime=new Date().getTime();  exports.handler=function(event,context) {           var payload=new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('ascii');  var params = {
        FunctionName: "ChainFunc2",
        InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
        Payload: JSON.stringify({"starttime": start.getTime()})
    };      var lambdaClient = new AWS.Lambda();

Comment: lambdaClient.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("invoke failed:" + err, err.stack);
            context.fail(err);
        } else {
            console.log("invoke succeeded", data);
            context.succeed(data);
        }   });
    });  };

Comment: Now this the code for my lambda function ChainFunc2 :: var AWS = require("aws-sdk");  console.log("Received event:", JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)); exports.handler = function(event, context) {  console.log("Received event:", JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));   var startTime = event.starttime;  var params = {
            FunctionName: "ChainFunc3",
        InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
        Payload: JSON.stringify({"starttime": starttime})
        };                                                                                                   var lambdaClient = new AWS.Lambda();

Comment: lambdaClient.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("invoke failed:" + err, err.stack);
            context.fail(err);
        } else {
            console.log("invoke succeeded", data);
            context.succeed(data);
        } }); };

Comment: The code which I have written for ChainFunc2 is the same code i am using for ChainFunc3,4,5 except that in the "params" field i am changing the function name....For ChainFunc1 i am using "lambda kinesis template" & for other Lambda functions i.e. ChainFunc2,3,4 i am using "cloudwatch logs template" ...I saw in Cloudwatch that logs ChainFunc2 are showing sometime the correct values sometime some unrelated logs related to aws & same i am facing in ChainFunc3,4 etc....

Comment: Basically I am doing lambda chaining as I want to note the time it takes for lambda chaining to complete i.e. note the time at 1st lambda function invocation & note the time at suppose 8th lambda function which will give me the total time invocation required for invoking lambda functions